# Why am I getting a cannot implicitly convert int to bool error?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, viewmodel, dao

I don't understand why its saying that I'm trying to convert a int to a bool. It may be a simple problem but its going over my head. Can anyone see my issue. I am getting my error in my Unit Test on the "if (dao.Update(call))" and "if (vm.Update())". It says I cannot implicitly convert int to bool. Could it be my Update method for my DAO and ViewModel? Thanks in advance for anyone who can help me out. Cheers.

Here is my entity class:

```
public class Call : IMongoEntity
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public string _accessId { get; set; }
        public ObjectId EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public ObjectId ProblemId { get; set; }
        public ObjectId TechId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateOpened { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime? DateClosed { get; set; }
        public bool OpenStatus { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my DAO Code:

```
public int Update(Call call)
        {
            int updateOK = -1;
            try
            {
                DbContext ctx = new DbContext();
                ctx.Save<Call>(call, "calls");
                updateOK = 1;
            }
            catch (MongoConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                updateOK = -2;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Problem " + ex.Message);
                DALUtils.ErrorRoutine(ex, "CallDAO", "Update");
            }
            return updateOK;
        }
```

Here is my ViewModel Code:

```
public int Update()
        {
            int rowsUpdated = -1;
            try
            {
                Call call = new Call();
                call.DateOpened = DateOpened;
                call.DateClosed = DateClosed;
                call.OpenStatus = OpenStatus;
                call.Notes = Notes;
                rowsUpdated = _dao.Update(call);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewModelsUitls.ErrorRoutine(ex, "CallViewModel", "Update");
            }
            return rowsUpdated;
        }
```

And here's my Unit Testing Code for the DAO and ViewModel:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void CallDAOComprehensiveTestsReturnTrue()
        {
            CallDAO dao = new CallDAO();
            Call call = new Call();
            call.DateOpened = DateTime.Now;
            call.DateClosed = null;
            call.OpenStatus = true;
            call.EmployeeId = new MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId("56527d3e3e400c1adc33ad37"); // bigshot
            call.TechId = new MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId("56527d3e3e400c1adc33ad3d"); // Burner
            call.ProblemId = new MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId("56527d3e3e400c1adc33ad44");//memory
            call.Notes = "Bigshot has bad RAM, Burner to fix it";
            string newId = dao.Create(call);
            this.testContextInstance.WriteLine("New Call Id == " + newId);
            call = dao.GetById(newId);
            this.testContextInstance.WriteLine("Call retrieved");
            call.Notes = call.Notes + "\nOrdered new Ram";

            if (dao.Update(call))
                this.testContextInstance.WriteLine("Call was updated " + call.Notes);
            else
                Trace.WriteLine("Call was not updated");

            if (dao.Delete(newId))
                this.testContextInstance.WriteLine("call was deleted");
            else
                this.testContextInstance.WriteLine("call was not deleted");
            call = dao.GetById(newId);
            Assert.IsNull(call);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(MongoDB.Driver.MongoException),"No Id exists")]
        public void CallViewModelComprehensiveTestsReturnTrue()
        {
            CallViewModel vm = new CallViewModel();
            vm.DateOpened = DateTime.Now;
            vm.OpenStatus = true;
            vm.EmployeeId = "56527d3e3e400c1adc33ad37"; // Bigshot
            vm.TechId = "56527d3e3e400c1adc33ad3d"; // Burner
            vm.ProblemId = "56527d3e3e400c1adc33ad44"; // memory
            vm.Notes = "Bigshot has ban RAM, Burner to fix it";
            vm.Create();
            this.testContextInstance.WriteLine("New call Id == " + vm.Id);
            vm.GetById(vm.Id);
            this.testContextInstance.WriteLine("Call retrieved");
            vm.Notes = vm.Notes + "\nOrdered new Ram";

            if (vm.Update())
                this.testContextInstance.WriteLine("Call was updated " + vm.Notes);
            else
                Trace.WriteLine("Call was not updated");

            if (vm.Delete(vm.Id))
                this.testContextInstance.WriteLine("Call was deleted");
            else
                this.testContextInstance.WriteLine("Call was not deleted");

            vm.Update(); // should throw MongoException see attribute
        }
```

Comment: `Update` returns an integer. You can't treat that as a boolean. What part of the message is confusing?

Comment: @DanielKelley Yes I understand that but how am I converting to a bool?

Comment: Your usage of `if` - that expects a boolean. Imagine `Update` returns 10 - your code translates to `if(10)` - what does that mean?

Comment: You're saying `if(Update() == true)` basically.

Comment: @markoGrbovic the error is telling you exactly what the issue is.. us the debugger to step through your own code.. and see where or why `if (dao.Update(call))` is trying to evaluate an `Int to a bool` perhaps you need to do `if (dao.Update(call) > -1)` some int value `public int Update()` returns an Integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an if statement checks if the arguments are true, and then executes the code within the block.

```
dao.Update(call)
```

returns an integer. An integer is not a boolean. Placing it within an if statement as you have is the equivalent of doing

```
if (dao.Update(call) == true)
```

which translates to

```
if ([integer value] == true)
```

which is why you get the error you see.

What you need to do is either change the return type of `Update()` to be boolean, or else do a check on the integer returned is an expected value, e.g.

```
if (dao.Update(call) > 0)
```